# Subset of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

Consider matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a-b \end{bmatrix}$ with entries from $\mathbb{R}$, closed under addition and matrix multiplication (see [Unital rings within matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663801/unital-rings-within-matrices) ). This forms a unital and commutative ring.

Moreover, the determinant of such a matrix is of the form $x^2 + y^2 - xy = f(x,y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Notice that $f_x = 2x - y$ and $f_y = 2y - x$, so the only possible extremum is at the critical point $(0,0)$, and for large $(x,y)$ we have positive $f(x,y)$, so I suspect that $f(x,y) > 0$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. So all nonzero matrices of this form are invertible, which means this ring is a field. Call it $M$.

Is there a more well-known field $K$ such that $M \cong K$? I notice that $M \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ with multiplication defined as $(a,b) * (c,d) = (ac-bd, ad+bc-bd)$, which is close to defining it as $(ac-bd, ad+bc)$ for $\mathbb{C}$.

---

EDIT: there are much simpler ways to prove $x^2+y^2-xy \neq 0$ if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. [How can I prove that $xy\leq x^2+y^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357272/how-can-i-prove-that-xy-leq-x2y2/357281#357281)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with $\Bbb{R}[\omega]=\{a+b\omega \, | \, a,b \in \Bbb{R}\}$, Eisenstein ring, where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity?

Here the norm $|a+b\omega|$ is defined as $(a+b\omega)(a+b\omega^2)=a^2-ab+b^2$.

If you are "determined" you can find the isomorphism:-)

Comment: . . . n i c e . . .

Comment: $(a+b\omega)*(c+d\omega) = (ac - bd) + (ad+bc-bd)\omega$, so one ring isomorphism is $f:\mathbb{R}[\omega] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $f(a+b\omega) = (a,b)$.